# Viability of lasers in space

Tags: science-based, spaceships, lasers

Specifically, if lasers were to be used as a weapon, or as a mining tool, for a spaceship, would it be at all practical? Most spaceships in my world are made of aluminum and/or titanium, at least those built to be able to land. Many spaceships do have windows. I am wondering if firing into a window would be viable, or if that could be protected against easily enough.

Comment: Hi Kraken, and welcome to Worldbuilding.  This kind of question [is asked](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/154870/what-are-the-limits-of-laser-weapons-in-space?rq=1) [a lot](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55016/laser-weapons-in-space-distance-and-focal-lenses?rq=1).  As such, this question is likely to be (and should be) closed as duplicate unless there's something unique you mean to ask.  I suggest checking out all the other questions about lasers in space and _then_ updating your question.

Comment: *"If that could be protected against easily enough":* [Window shutters](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fenetre_bleue_Jurilovca_Musee_Village_Bucarest.jpg) were invented thousands of years *before* window glass panes...

Comment: Have you researched what modern militaries have done to protect (e.g.) tanks against lasers?